# Find GPX files which contain tracks located in a specified bounding box

Tags: extents, gpsbabel, gpx

I have a bunch of GPX files and I want to find out which files contain tracks located in certain geographic extent, e.g. files containing tracks in Pennsylvania. Also, the inverse is also useful too, e.g. any file containing tracks *not* in USA. How to do this using any command line tool?

Gpsbabel's [polygon filter](http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-development/filter_polygon.html) looks like what I want. But for some reason I could not make it work. The filter does not filter anything. I am not sure whether the polygon filter works with track data. This is how I run it:

```
gpsbabel -i gpx -f infile.gpx -x polygon,file=test_bb.txt -o gpx -F outfile.gpx
```

Adding `exclude` suboption to polygon filter does not make any different to the output as well.

Comment: Thanks for your question. You have written a perfect example of *how to filter waypoints*, which was my endeavour when filtering my favourites from [OSMAnd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OsmAnd) by a specific region (polygon). The only thing I had to look for, was the [`polygonfile` syntax](https://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-1.5.1/filter_polygon.html), which is a list of latitudes and longitudes, one latitude and longitude separated by space per line **and** the last line has to be the same as the first line (closed polygon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about gpsbabel, but here are a few examples with OGR: if you just need an approximation, you can use:

```
ogrinfo -al -so infile.gpx
```

Which will give you the binding box. Similarly, you can use `ogr2ogr` to pull out geometries which overlap a spatial extent with `-spat`:

```
ogr2ogr -spat xmin ymin xmax ymax filtered.gpx infile.gpx
```

If binding boxes are insufficient, you could write a Python script which used Shapely's [Intersection()](http://gispython.org/shapely/docs/1.0/manual.html#intersection).

Comment: ogrinfo is just what I need. I eventually used `ogrinfo -so infile.gpx -spat xmin ymin xmax ymax | grep 'Extent'`. If there are tracks in the given bounding box, the Extent value will be available.

Answer (score 1):

According to [capabilities page](http://www.gpsbabel.org/capabilities.html) gpsbabel's polygon filter only supports waypoints.